# How to collect messages (total number and size) between microservices?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microservices, instrumentation, zipkin

I have a microservices based software architecture.

There is a php application which orchestrates the communication among microservices and the application's whole logic.

I need to simulate the communication between microservices as a graph.

There will be edges with weights , which will represent the affinities between microservices.

I am searching for a tool in order to collect all messages and their size.

I have read that there are distibuted tracing systems like Zipkin which i have already deployed, and could accomplish this task.

But, i cannot find how to collect the messages i want.

This is the php library i used for the instrumentation of my app

[https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin-php]

Any ideas about other tools or how to use Zipkin differently to achieve my goal?

Comment: Hello.Have I understood you correctly that you are looking for a way to collect the information about the requests that your microservices are sending between each other (the count of it and size of each request)? Have you checked [Jaeger](https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.21/operator/) by any chance?

Comment: Yes i know also Jaeger , i have read that it does the same job as Zipkin i described above. Do you know if Jaeger needs instrumentation of my app?

Comment: Jaeger in fact rely mainly on Prometheus metrics, so if your instrumented app already exposes such metrics like (request_size|response_size), you are good to go with Jaeger. Where do you run you microservices currently, on top of Kubernetes?

Comment: I have a deployment both on docker and on kubernetes. No problem with that. But my main problem is, how can i instrument a microservice if i am using it as a black box. There are some microservices on my architecture that have not been implemented by me. So it is difficult to inject code inside their source code in order to make them compatible with jaeger or zipkin. I have read that there are some proxies that simplify the job such as Envoy. Do you know something for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me add to this thread my three bits. Speaking of Envoy, yes, when attached to your application it adds a lot of useful features from observability bucket, e.g. network level statistics and tracing.

Here is the question, have you considered running your legacy apps inside service mesh, like Istio ?.

Istio simplifies deployment and configuration of Envoy for you. It injects sidecar container (istio-proxy, in fact Envoy instance) to your Pod application, and gives you these extra features like a set of service metrics out of the box*.

Example: Stats produced by Envoy in Prometheus format, like `istio_request_bytes` are visualized in Kiali Metrics dashboard for inbound traffic as `request_size` (check screenshot)

*as mentioned by @David Kruk, you still needs to have Prometheus server deployed in your cluster to be able to pull these metrics to Kiali dashboards.

You can learn more about Istio [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/examples/microservices-istio/). There is also a dedicated section on how to [visualize metrics](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/kiali/) collected by Istio (e.g. request size).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Istio collects tracing data by itself? Because i have read that it needs Jaeger or Zipkin to be integrated with it. Am i wright? If yes, so i need envoy,istio,a tracing system and a service for visualiation of the metrics such as promitheus and kiali?

Comment: Correct, tracing data needs to be pushed to one of 5 tracers currently [supported](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/istio.mesh.v1alpha1/#Tracing) by Istio. To simplify your journey with Istio, there is a demo profile, which installs all necessary  components for you (including Jaeger and Prometheus). Please refer to Istio's "getting started" setup to check all these telemetry applications in action.

Comment: Actually, Istio does not *need* any tracing server like jaeger or zipkin. Tracing is possible but not mandatory. You can still use istio without tracing, you'll still get the metrics (with prometheus), the service graph in kiali, etc.

Comment: And to add a bit more, metrics are actually more relevant than traces to get aggregated information like number of messages, sizes, response times etc. Traces give more precision (more metadata, and chaining of events) on samples.